# How can I get rounded corners without using overflow: hidden or applying border-radius to an unknown number of child elements?

Tags: html, css, rounded-corners

I have a container element that should have rounded corners. This element (`well`) should be a piece of reusable HTML and CSS that can contain a few common children with established styles such as primary or secondary regions (`well__primary`, `well__secondary`) as well as the possibility for a one-off style (`well__custom`). These second-level elements can be used in an arbitrary order and amount and each second-level element can contain arbitrary children elements.

To start with, I was using `border-radius` on the outermost container coupled with `overflow: hidden` to prevent the squared corners of the inner elements from leaking out. This worked fine:

```css
.body {
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 1em;
}

.well {
  margin: 1em 0 0 0;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.well__primary {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.well__secondary {
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.well--first {
  border-top-left-radius: 1em;
  border-top-right-radius: 1em;
}

.well--last {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 1em;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 1em;
}

.item {
  padding: 1em;
}

.item--special {
  display: flex;
}

.item--special-left {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background-color: #88f;
}

.item--special-right {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background-color: #8f8;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div class="well">
    <div class="well__primary">
      <div class="item">Primary content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="well__secondary">
      <div class="item">Secondary content</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="well">
    <div class="well__secondary">
      <div class="item">Secondary content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="well__primary">
      <div class="item">Primary content</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="well">
    <div class="well__primary">
      <div class="item">Primary content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="well__custom">
      <div class="item--special">
        <div class="item item--special-left">Left</div>
        <div class="item item--special-right">Right</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

We then started using a third party component (`awkward`) that uses absolute positioning to show an editing panel. Parts of the panel were hidden because it overflowed the container.

We are OK if the panel actually extends beyond the container, but having it be cut-off makes it impossible to use. When the whole panel is shown, its visual aspects are fine.

```css
.body {
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 1em;
}

.well {
  margin: 1em 0 0 0;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.well__primary {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.well__secondary {
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.item {
  padding: 1em;
}

.item--special {
  display: flex;
}

.item--special-left {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background-color: #88f;
}

.item--special-right {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background-color: #8f8;
}

.awkward {
  position: relative;
}

.awkward__text {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f88;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div class="well">
    <div class="well__primary">
      <div class="item">Primary content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="well__secondary">
      <div class="item">
        Secondary content
        <div class="awkward">
          <div class="awkward__text">Hello</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="well">
    <div class="well__secondary">
      <div class="item">Secondary content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="well__primary">
      <div class="item">
        Primary content
        <div class="awkward">
          <div class="awkward__text">Hello</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="well">
    <div class="well__primary">
      <div class="item">Primary content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="well__custom">
      <div class="item--special">
        <div class="item item--special-left">
          Left
          <div class="awkward">
            <div class="awkward__text">Hello</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item item--special-right">Right</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I attempted to solve this by adding classes (`well--first`, `well--last`) to the first and last direct children of the well and applying the `border-radius` to those, but this doesn't work when the element contained within *those* elements is the one to specify the background color, as now that element is spilling outside of the border radius:

```css
.body {
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 1em;
}

.well {
  margin: 1em 0 0 0;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.well__primary {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.well__secondary {
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.well--first {
  border-top-left-radius: 1em;
  border-top-right-radius: 1em;
}

.well--last {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 1em;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 1em;
}

.item {
  padding: 1em;
}

.item--special {
  display: flex;
}

.item--special-left {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background-color: #88f;
}

.item--special-right {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background-color: #8f8;
}

.awkward {
  position: relative;
}

.awkward__text {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f88;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div class="well">
    <div class="well__primary well--first">
      <div class="item">Primary content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="well__secondary well--last">
      <div class="item">
        Secondary content
        <div class="awkward">
          <div class="awkward__text">Hello</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="well">
    <div class="well__secondary well--first">
      <div class="item">Secondary content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="well__primary well--last">
      <div class="item">
        Primary content
        <div class="awkward">
          <div class="awkward__text">Hello</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="well">
    <div class="well__primary well--first">
      <div class="item">Primary content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="well__custom well--last">
      <div class="item--special">
        <div class="item item--special-left">
          Left
          <div class="awkward">
            <div class="awkward__text">Hello</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item item--special-right">Right</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't want to have to modify the CSS of an arbitrary number of components (`item*`) just to give them rounded corners. I'd rather modify the CSS of the `well*` classes once.

---

This is within a React application where I am striving to create a reusable `Well` component. The code would look like

```
<Well>
  <WellPrimary>
    Primary content
  </WellPrimary>
  <WellSecondary>
    Secondary content
  </WellSecondary>
  <WellCustom>
    Custom content
  </WellCustom>
</Well>
```

Where `WellPrimary`, `WellSecondary` and `WellCustom` can all come in arbitrary order and amount, and the children of each of those three components is also arbitrary.

Comment: For rounded corners with a 'fill' colour, you have to apply `border-radius` to the element that adds the background itself. Can you not just add a `border-radius` to `.awkward__text`?

Comment: @ObsidianAge maybe I did a poor job of explaining? `.awkward__text` should not have rounded corners. That's the absolutely positioned panel that is provided by a third party and I don't have have direct control over.

Comment: Can `.well__secondary`/`.well__primary`/`.well__custom` scroll? If not, what are you trying to do about the third party bit to fix it extending outside the container – make the container bigger?

Comment: @cjl750 Hadn't thought of vertical scrolling at all, honestly. I'm actually OK with the panel extending beyond the container. I'd also be OK if the panel took up space when it was shown, but I'm under the impression that the absolute positioning of the panel takes it out of the flow so that's not possible. I'd like to avoid adding blank area to the container at all times as it would be quite an eyesore when it's not open. It also wouldn't be very flexible as the container would have to know *all* possible heights of *any* child that might *ever* occur within it.

Comment: I see what the issue is now. Unfortunately I don't have a fix for you besides using the wildcard selector to give a border radius to all the children. Couldn't come up with anything else. The other hacky solution I can think of is you can create a small, square image that's transparent except one corner that is filled with your page's background color, and overlay it on top of `.well__first` and `.well__last` as a `background-image` of a pseudo element. Idk how to make that shape (including the curve to match the border radius) in CSS, though.

Comment: border radius is so 2010ish ʘ‿ʘ

Comment: @Christoph removing the `border-radius` is the nuclear option here, but it's still on the table. The curve isn't *vital* to the design of the page, but I'm never happy with changing the design to workaround annoying details that feel like it's my own problem.

Answer (score 2):

Is inheritance an option? (e.g. `border-bottom-left-radius: inherit;`).  Note that I also had `.item--special` inherit border radius.

```css
.body {
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 1em;
}

.well {
  margin: 1em 0 0 0;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.well__primary {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.well__secondary {
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.well--first {
  border-top-left-radius: 1em;
  border-top-right-radius: 1em;
}

.well--last {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 1em;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 1em;
}

.item {
  padding: 1em;
}

.item--special {
  display: flex;
  border-radius: inherit;
}

.item--special-left {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background-color: #88f;
  border-bottom-left-radius: inherit;
}

.item--special-right {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background-color: #8f8;
  border-bottom-right-radius: inherit;
}

.awkward {
  position: relative;
}

.awkward__text {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f88;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div class="well">
    <div class="well__primary well--first">
      <div class="item">Primary content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="well__secondary well--last">
      <div class="item">
        Secondary content
        <div class="awkward">
          <div class="awkward__text">Hello</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="well">
    <div class="well__secondary well--first">
      <div class="item">Secondary content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="well__primary well--last">
      <div class="item">
        Primary content
        <div class="awkward">
          <div class="awkward__text">Hello</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="well">
    <div class="well__primary well--first">
      <div class="item">Primary content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="well__custom well--last">
      <div class="item--special">
        <div class="item item--special-left">
          Left
          <div class="awkward">
            <div class="awkward__text">Hello</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item item--special-right">Right</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

## edit:

Here's a solution using masking.

```css
.body {
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 1em;
}

.well {
  margin: 1em 0 0 0;
}

.well__primary {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.well__secondary {
  background-color: #eee;
}

.well--first, .well--last {
  position: relative;
}

.well--first:before {
    content: '';
    width: 2em;
    height: 2em;
    position: absolute;
    top: -1em;
    left: -1em;
    border-top-left-radius: 1em;
    box-shadow: inset 0.5em 0.5em 0em 0.5em black;
}

.well--first:after {
    content: '';
    width: 2em;
    height: 2em;
    position: absolute;
    top: -1em;
    right: -1em;
    border-top-right-radius: 1em;
    box-shadow: inset -0.5em 0.5em 0em 0.5em black;
}

.well--last:before {
    content: '';
    width: 2em;
    height: 2em;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -1em;
    left: -1em;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 1em;
    box-shadow: inset 0.5em -0.5em 0em 0.5em black;
}

.well--last:after {
    content: '';
    width: 2em;
    height: 2em;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -1em;
    right: -1em;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 1em;
    box-shadow: inset -0.5em -0.5em 0em 0.5em black;
}

.item {
  padding: 1em;
}

.item--special {
  display: flex;
}

.item--special-left {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background-color: #88f;
}

.item--special-right {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background-color: #8f8;
}

.awkward {
  position: relative;
}

.awkward__text {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f88;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div class="well">
    <div class="well__primary well--first">
      <div class="item">Primary content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="well__secondary well--last">
      <div class="item">
        Secondary content
        <div class="awkward">
          <div class="awkward__text">Hello</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="well">
    <div class="well__secondary well--first">
      <div class="item">Secondary content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="well__primary well--last">
      <div class="item">
        Primary content
        <div class="awkward">
          <div class="awkward__text">Hello</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="well">
    <div class="well__primary well--first">
      <div class="item">Primary content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="well__custom well--last">
      <div class="item--special">
        <div class="item item--special-left">
          Left
          <div class="awkward">
            <div class="awkward__text">Hello</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item item--special-right">Right</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Am I correct in understanding that every element that might ever want to be placed inside the well would need to have `border-radius: inherit` set, just in case it was placed within the well?

Comment: @Shepmaster Unfortunately, yes.  With this method, you would need to ensure any descendant element with a background are either mimicking or inheriting the border radius.  The real problem here is that border radius needs to have `overflow:hidden` if a background is being used, but you can't pick and choose which elements overflow and which do not.  What about a mask?  Is the background (black part in the demo) consistently a solid color?  You could create the rounded corner effect using pseudo-elements that just make the corners look like they're transparent by matching the background color.

Comment: Ah, it even looks like each component would have to be cognizant of *where* it is in the well. Setting `border-radius: inherit` instead of `border-bottom-right-radius: inherit` on `.item--special-right` causes the middle of the well's bottom border to have the rounded corner, which wouldn't be desired.

Comment: *Is the background consistently a solid color?* — yes, I believe that it is in this case. I'd appreciate seeing how that type of solution might look; I played a tiny bit with a similar idea but couldn't figure out how to get the right shape.

Comment: @Shepmaster Purely "for science" I've made a demo that uses the inside of a border radius with a box shadow (to keep it from affecting the size) on a transparent pseudo-element.  This it not at all ideal.  I would recommend just using an image.  You can base-64 encode it if you have to; but in any case, it is theoretically possible to create this shape.  I don't recommend it.  You can see my edit for how I did it.  The only important changes to other elements I made is that I had to add position:relative to the containers and `z-index: 1` to the awkward text.